# Blocked loading mixed active content "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" while enable SSL website

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, facebook, ssl

I have a mvc 4 application (using nopCommerce) with Facebook sharing option. last month

we need to enable SSL settings in our website. But now our Facebook sharing option is

not working correctly in the website.I use firebug in firefox browser for exact error

message.

[image]

i already replace all the HTTP to HTTPS in my HTML. but the firebug shows HTTP in every

time. Please see the script below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=nopsolutions"></script>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
    appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    cookie: true,
    status: true,
    xfbml: true
});

function FacebookInviteFriends() {

    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Test message content.',

    });
}
function callback(response) {
    // response.to now contain array of invited users ids
    console.log('Invited friends ids', response.to);
    if (response.request) {
        console.log('Efficient Request id', response.request);
    } else {
        console.log('Requests Ids', response.request_ids);
    }
}
```

**Source of Firefox**

[image]

**At the same time the twitter is works well in https.**

[image]

I don't know where the script reference coming in the firebug. Please Help.

Comment: I know it is obvious but make sure your page isn't caching something weird. Check the actual code on the DOM and see if the src is actually set to https and not http. Do this by clicking HTML in the console or just inspect the elements on the page.

Comment: But i am looking all over the project i didn't see any http link all are https.

Comment: Yeah. Just check the page in the browser. Right click and click `inspect with firebug` or whatever. Look in the head and see if it says `https` and not `http`.

Comment: I update my question in html source it's displayed http.

Comment: You are using many images of code. There is no reason to snapshot them, crop them, then upload them. Just copy the code into the code blocks. It makes it easier to read. You can do the same with the errors too but that isn't as big of a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your most recent update I see that `http` is still being used even though you have changed it to `https` in your code. You most likely just need to clear your cache. In firefox you will have to :

```
click on the Firefox menu on the menu bar and select Preferences
Select the Advanced panel
Click on the Network tab
In the Cached Web Content section, click Clear Now
```

The browser caches the page so it doesn't have to hit the server every time you go to that page. The old html file is being cached and the new revisions are not being loaded. If clearing the cache doesn't work let me know and I will look for another solution.

Another good solution to your problem with mixed http and https is to just leave them off all together. If you just use `src="//s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=nopsolutions"` it will match what the page is set to so if you are at `https://youriste.com` it will default to `https://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=nopsolutions"`.

Comment: Also... It is even more obvious but make sure you are saving the files to the right place. Make sure you are editing the files and saving them over the existing ones and not somewhere else. This is very basic stuff but we all make mistakes. If this doesn't solve your problem please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable reply. i try this way. I should inform you. Again said thanks.

Comment: I cleared the Cached Web Content in my Firefox browser. but the same problem again. I check my webpage source again but the reference link coming from http.

Comment: Hi, I have same situation i am also cleared  cache but i have getting same problem.

Comment: @DutGRIFF Thank you very much for you great help. Your are right.
the problem is our facebook share screen is seperate partial view.
we use this as a popup. we place this partial view file in 
Views/Shared folder and call this view file in another controller view ( Controller name is CheckOutController ).it's works correctly in our localhost but when we upload this code in live IIS, we need to move this partial view to Views/CheckOut folder. I forgot this matter. We always upload the changes in to this Shared folder. forgot to change the partial view in Views/CheckOut folder.

Comment: Our partial view is working only when it's place on the parent view folder ( Views/Checkout ). When we move this on Views/Shared folder 
it's shows the error. This is the main reason to arise this problem.

Comment: It's solved we used the RenderPartial("FacebookShare") instead of Render("FacebookShare"). Now it's solved.